# Land value tax in GDP accounting

Tags: gdp, taxation

Using the Income Approach, it seems like a land value tax is counted as an "other taxes on production" component of GDP. But I don't understand why and how it counts as a tax on production when it's actually closer to a wealth tax. And since it pays for government spending including public sector wages, it's kind of like the public sector's contribution would be counted twice.

What do I get wrong ? Is government spending counted as a subsidy to be subtracted ?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between "taxes on production" and "taxes on products": income taxes are typically the former and excise taxes the latter (subsidies effectively negative taxes on products).  Land value taxes can be see as a form of tax on that (potential) part of production or income deriving from the value of land.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply, I really didn't expect a quick answer. So if I get it right, land value taxes are not included in GDP calculation?